# Как удалить дочерний элемент в firebase?

Tags: android-studio, firebase

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Доброй ночи,а кому-то и утра! Новичок в андроид разработке...тут нужна помощь,споткнулся на том,что когда зажимаешь по View-элементу,появляется меню с просьбой удалить ли ЭТОТ элемент...но вот я и не могу ЭТОТ самый элемент удалить,он удаляет все элементы из БД...[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Q6v0.jpg)[введите сюда описание изображения]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2hbgB.png)[[image: введите сюда описание изображения]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q3kBy.png)

Comment: Код пожалуйста разместите как код. Скриншоты с кодом запрещены

Answer (score 0):

так нужно выбрать что удалять (стоит ref.child("items") - а это корень).

Если пользователь выбирает удалить "dbbb" далее:

```
ref.child("items").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener(){
 @Override
  public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    for (DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
      String keyDelete = ds.getKey();
      // тут читаешь в свой класс значение
      YourClass item = ds.getValue(YourClass.class);
      if (значение выбранное пользователем == item.name){
       ref.child("items").child(keyDelete).removeValue();
       braek; // если значение одно выходим из цикла, если нужно все такие записи удалить, то убрать эту строчку
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: спасибо за то,что уделили время,но строка:
if (значение выбранное пользователем == item.name)
выделяется красным слово NAME...и как в условии указать то значение,которое выбрал пользователь?

Comment: цитата: "когда зажимаешь по View-элементу,появляется меню с просьбой удалить ли ЭТОТ элемент." ЭТОТ элемент это что? если это элемент класса, который содержит "name", то берешь этот name и сравниваешь со всеми значениями снимка dataSnapshot. А если нет, то что удалять-то нужно?

Comment: И еще по дистингу YourClass - это Item, но в нем  нет гетеров и сетеров. getName() и getPrice() - методов возвращающих значения полей класса.

Comment: не помогло...в условии не могу указать ЭТОТ элемент

Comment: даже мне не понятно, что такое ЭТОТ элемент, что уж говорить об андроиде. Откуда он берется?

Comment: Через адаптер добавляется